# How to pass array of byte from javascript to ActiveX

Tags: javascript, activex

I want to call method of an ActiveX
BOOL GetMinutiaeData(const VARIANT FAR& MinutiaeData)

and here's my calling javascript:

```
    var data = new Array();
    document.getElementById("objFP").GetMinutiaeData(data);
    alert(document.getElementById("objFP").ErrorString);
```

the ErrorString is "Invalid Parameter". anyone has answer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Scripting.Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28VS.85%29.aspx) is what you need:

```
var y = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Dictionary");
y.add (0, "a");
y.add (0, "b");

document.getElementById("objFP").SetArrayProp(y.Items());
```